# strip a class after jquery UI droppable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to strip a class after it has been dropped on the correct area. It's then used in a countdown. This is a class added in html and not part of UI.

```
drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        followOn(draggedItem),
        $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ).css("background-color", "green").draggable( "option", "disabled", true ),
        $( ui.draggable ).remove(draggedItem)
    }
```

I don't quite understand the comma separated commands used here. It seems anything after the disabled option gets ignored but if I remove the class before it, it errors out. Using remove() gets rid of the whole div.

Comment: by strip a class do you mean **[remove class](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)**?

Comment: yes,  I want to remove a class added in html after the drop event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the class, you can select whichever element it is you will remove a class from and remove it like this:

```
$("someElement").removeClass("someClassName");
```

If I understood you correctly you mean to remove a class from the element who has the `ui-draggable` class. Which in your case translates to:

```
$( ui.draggable ).removeClass("someclass");
```

Comment: where would I add this. after disable would seem like the logical place but nothing executes after disable.

Comment: @ryan you should first try removing it anywhere in your code after you are certain that the element has the class, at least for test purposes. If that works then you are certain that your selector within the `$("someselectorhere")` is properly removing the class. From there, it's not clear where to put it from your code, but if it was me trying for the first time and assuming your `drop` function will indeed remove the class, then I would do it after `drop` has been executed or within `drop` itself

Comment: Your answer is correct for the question I asked. I was apparently asking the wrong question. Turned out all I had to do was remove the event listener. Thank you.

Comment: @ryan live and learn right, it's all part of the learning curve my friend